# Receiving multiple alert messages from jsTree search

Tags: javascript, jstree

I have built the function below to search for text in [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/).

If the search text is found, hightlight the node. If not found, alert user with *"No node with the search string, try again"* string.

What happens is when I put a search text that is not in jsTree, I get the alert. I search again with a valid text for the nodes but I still get the alert on the browser window.

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function myFunction()
{
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var value=document.getElementById("search_field").value;    
        var searchResult;
        var AlertsOn = false

        $("#search_tree").click(function () { 
            searchResult=$("#tree").jstree("search",value);
                if ($(searchResult).find('.jstree-search').length == 0) 
                {
                    AlertsOn = true;
                }
                else 
                {
                    AlertsOn = false;
                }

                if(AlertsOn == true){
                    alert($(searchResult).find('.jstree-search').length);
                }       
        });
        document.getElementById("search_field").value='';
    }); 
}
</script>
```

html:

```
<fieldset id="search">

    <input type="text" name="search_field" id="search_field" value="" />
    <button id="search_tree" onclick="myFunction()"> Search</button>

  </fieldset>
```

Comment: Could you provide working jsfiddle?

Comment: Are you sure that value is actually getting set to the search text entered by the user?

Comment: @elevine, yes. I update my post and included the search_field textbox.

Comment: is it possible to re-initialize the alert right after every clic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can do this call in jquery to reload the page to re-initialize the alert box:

```
location.reload();
```